# preloading ad view

Tags: android, view, mobclix

i have aplication with a very short lifespan.
in most cases a services pops a activity and the user reacts within a few seconds and dismisses the poped activity.

In this activity i show a mobclix advertisment.
But loading of this takes about 5 seconds, this is to long for my use.

So can i preload this ad in the service , and display it directly as i display my activity?

thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It's a problem I'm having too. Thanks!

Comment: no.. i asked mobclix and they answered it's not possible. now i display a "loading ads" box for the time it loads.